# what is purpose of JSP compilation?

Tags: java, html, jsp, compilation

I am currently making some changes in JSP and uploading it to server and then compiling it.

After compilation, it generates a `.class` file of that JSP.

If i remove the JSP from the server, will it work as server will only reads `.class` file of that JSP ?

Comment: JSP From Server means ? Deleting all jsp file from `webapps' directory of tomcat? or any other server ? Any specific reason

Comment: The purpose of compiling JSPs is...to compile them. To turn source code into bytecode, which can then be run in a Java container (such as a servlet engine). What's the real question?

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of any compiling?

Well in this case, it's purpose is to translate the nice looking templating language into runnable .class code that the server will execute. JVM can execute only Java stuff (i.e. .class files). Same goes for .java files. They look nice, but they cannot be run as .java files, they must be compiled first.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the JSP it will give HTTP Status 404 with the description "description:The requested resource (/yourJSPpage.jsp) is not available."

Because,
each time the browser sends an http request for a JSP file the JSP engine of the server loads the JSP file.

Then JSP is converted to the Servlet file and then it is converted to the class file.

If you send a new request for the same JSP file the JSP engine checks whether the generated servlet file exists or not.If exists it checks whether its modification date is older than the JSP.If older (JSP has been modified) then JSP is converted to servlet again and generated servlet replaces the older one.

If you remove the JSP file JSP engine can't find the JSP file.So the server gives the above HTTP 404 status.